# Wildfly using MS SQL Server: why does it take two machines more time to process a job than one machine?

Tags: sql-server, windows, performance, jboss, wildfly

This is very puzzling. For a given job, one physical machine finishes the job in about 49 minutes. If I add another physical machine so now both machines each do parts of the job, it takes even longer - 53 minutes! 
Both machines operate on a database which is on a third machine.
**What could be causing this?** I would have expected the 2 machines to finish the job in close to half the time a single machine takes (so about 25 minutes)...

Let me describe the setup in more details:
This involves 3 Windows 7 machines (3 separate physical computers). Each having 8 cores.
A Wildfly 10 instance runs on each machine.

**Online server - Machine 1:** - the user interacts with this machine via a web interface.
   * This machine also hosts the database on an SQL Server.
   * When the user makes a request to run a certain job, the code breaks up the 
   job into smaller tasks. Each task is assigned an id. A JMS message is then 
   sent to a queue on this machine, for each task. The message holds the task 
   id.
   * So basically the job is divided up, information is written to the DB, and 
   now something needs to execute these tasks. They can be executed in any order.

**Batch Server - Machine 2** and **Batch Server - Machine 3** (two separate machines).
   * Each of these machines has its own Wildfly 10 instance running on it.
   * Each is configured to consume messages from the remote queue 
   defined in the Online sever (machine 1).
   * It does so via MDB using a pooled-connection-factory using a remote-connector.
   * The MDB in both machines is configured with maxSessions = 10 (also tried 8).
   * Upon receiving a message in the onMessage method, the code obtains the
    task id from the message, it then obtains the task information from the DB (which is on the Online Server (machine 1))
    and performs the work associated with this task id.

**Observations:**

- If machine 3 is offline and all the tasks of the job are executed by machine 2 it takes 49 minutes to complete the job.
- If both machines 2 and 3 are involved, it takes 53 minutes to complete the job.
- Looking at the target DataSource (in wildfly console of either machine) alsways shows:
  Available Conenctions: 248
  Active: 3
  Max Used: 17
- Average time to complete a task on machine 2 is longer when both machines 2 and 3 are processing the job, than when only machine 2 does so.
- The tasks are distributed very well - about equally - between the two batch servers.
- The Online server (which is also the database server) is not even close to full CPU utilization.
- The data source is configured in Wildfly as follows:

  ```
           <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/dbconn" jta="true" pool-name="MSSQLDS1" enabled="true" use-ccm="false" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="true"> 
              <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://wilxs185458-ftx:1433;DatabaseName=K11.2N;selectMethod=direct</connection-url> 
              <driver>sqlserver1</driver>
              <pool>
                  <min-pool-size>100</min-pool-size>
                  <max-pool-size>250</max-pool-size>

              </pool>
              <security>
                  <user-name>sa</user-name>
                  <password>password</password>
              </security>
              <statement>
                  <track-statements>true</track-statements>
                  <prepared-statement-cache-size>1000</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                  <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
              </statement>
          </datasource>
  ```

I have also experimented with the configuration maxSessions of the MDB (how many threads are processing the tasks in parallel) and running on just one Batch machine.
I observed that whether i use maxSessions 2, 4, or 8, The total work is completed in about the same amount of time.
I can also see from the logs that the threads are running in parallel according to maxSessions (as was expected) and when one finishes it immediately gets assigned another message (since each thread logs the time it starts processing the onMessage and the time it completes it).
The average time it takes to complete processing a task (the time it takes to process an onMessage method) is proportional to maxSessions.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Information Added 11/1/2017:**
I used YourKit Java Profiler (performance analyzer) and ran the same job twice. In both cases only Batch Server machine 1 was involved. The first time I ran it with the MDB annotated with maxSessions=8 and the second time maxSessions=4.

Looking even at the method java.lang.String.toLowerCase()
this method was called 312k times during the processing of the job, but the total time was 55174 milliseconds vs. 3003 milliseconds (8 threads vs. 4 threads). So doubling the number of threads has slowed down this method by an order of magnitude!

Comment: Presumably it depends on what the job actually does. For example, if one job updates a whole bunch of data which might make SQL Server take out page locks or table locks that block the other job, adding more machines might well slow things down...

Comment: How can that be looked at? is there a SQL Server command that would display the locking situation in real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was related to the network. The third machine which was just hosting the database was connected to a wall outlet which perhaps placed it on a worse network or something like that. Once i switched its wire to a different outlet things worked out well. (not sure about the technical terms). The key thing is that the machine on which i ran the database had  bad network bandwidth, The way i discovered that is this: i connected from one of the two Wildfly-hosting machines to that database-hosting machine using remote desktop, and copied a large file from the database machine to the wildfly machine and watched the network performance in the Resource Monitor. I observed a maximum of about 10Mbs. that was the red flag. After correcting the physical connection of the database machine, this file transfer was performing at about 100Mbs... and that also solved the problem above